# changing existing duplicate entries in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates

sorry for the (probably) noob question, but I', new at this stuff.

i have a table that has column 'position', and I want to, when inserting a new row, change positions of every row that has position lower than row that is inserted. for example, if I add row with position 4, if there is a duplicate, it should become 5, 5 should shift to 6 and so on...

also, is there a way to get highest value for column besides testing it in every row via php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two queries. Assuming you know the position you're inserting, increase the position of each row that has position greater than or equal to the position you're inserting:

```
UPDATE table SET position = position + 1 WHERE position >= newPosition
```

After that, the `newPosition` can be inserted and no duplicates will exist:

```
INSERT INTO table SET position = newPosition
```

To get the highest value, you can use `MAX()`

```
SELECT MAX(position) FROM table
```

Comment: damn, it worked for one row only. If I have more than one row that need to be updated, mysql says: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'position'
Any help?

Comment: dont mind my last post, I left 'unique' key on position... works fine